# Parsing xml android error

Tags: android, xml-parsing, xmldocument

I am trying to parse [this xml](http://1stfold.com/taskbox/Usman/tasks/giftList.xml) but when i parse i get given instead of valid xml.

```
XmlParser parser = new XmlParser();
                
xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl("http://1stfold.com/taskbox/Usman/tasks/giftList.xml");
```

but it add some `ï»¿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` before xml, other xml is fully parsed.

**XmlParse**

```
public class XmlParser 
{   
    public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) 
    {       
        String xml = null;
        try 
        {
            //default http client
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            
            System.out.println("URL IN PARSER:==="+url+"====");
            
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            
            HttpEntity httpentity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpentity);   
            
            Log.d("response", xml);
        } 
        catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        
        return xml;
    }
    
    public Document getDomElement(String xml)
    {   
        Document doc = null;
        
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        
        try
        {
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            
            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            
            doc = db.parse(is);
            
        } 
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (ParserConfigurationException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (SAXException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return doc;
    }                      
    
    public String getValue(Element item, String str)
    {   
        NodeList nl = item.getElementsByTagName(str);
        
        return this.getElementValue(nl.item(0));    
    }
    
    public final String getElementValue(Node elem)
    {   
        try
        {
            Node child;
            if(elem!=null)
            {
                if(elem.hasChildNodes())
                {
                    for(child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling())
                    {
                        if(child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE || child.getNodeType() == Node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE)
                        {
                            return child.getNodeValue().trim();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(DOMException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            
            return "";
                    
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

**Problem**

where am i doing wrong or why this error occur.I am using this same class in my old office(if i remember correctly) but it is appending `ï»¿` before xml,

**Edit**

Everything is working fine but I only have to replace ï»¿ from string. Share some code to replace ï»¿ from string..

Thanks in Advance....

Comment: Does the `getXmlFromUrl` method prefix `ï»¿` to the HTML of a simple web page, such as [End of Internet](http://hmpg.net/) ?

Comment: I got my answer i only have to replace ï»¿ from string .